# Issue while executing package

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaqcM.jpg)

I am not able to execute this package? i fixed run 64bitrun time to false and used Provider=SQLOLEDB

my source is oracle and destination is sql server

Comment: Looks like it is telling you the error you can not have special characters in the name, rename it and try again.

Comment: now i am not able to load the tables? I did set offline mode to true and unchecked workoffline

Answer (score 1):

Your package is set to Work Offline mode. You can change this by going to the menu bar. This feature is added to avoid long open times when packages are large.

SSIS -> Work Offline

http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2009/05/12/setting-work-offline-without-opening-the-project/